# Automatically set properties from the client side

Tags: c#, wcf, service, properties, setter

I am having a bit of a dilemna. Considering the following system:

[image]

And the following API:

```
IModule GetModule(string moduleName);
void SetModule(string moduleName);
```

Where each module contains a bunch of parameters.

A typical work flow would be the following one:

- Get a module (ie. local copy on the client side)
- Modify the parameter(s) of interest from that module
- Set the updated module (ie. call SetModule to update the actual system through the service/proxy)

Now the problem I am having with this workflow is that while a Client1 changes parameters a second client may be doing something based on wrong assumption of the internal state of the system.

Messaging will therefore need to be added to this implementation in order to keep the client in sync, but before that, something that could really help is to get rid of the SetModule() method and have parameters to automatically get updated when their value is changed on the client side.
The problem being that on the client side we actually have a copy of the object and not the actual system object, so is it even possible to do something of the sort:

```
moduleA = GetModule(string moduleName);
moduleA.enable = true;    ->   But when doing this, the setter for this parameter is called to directly update the param value from within the system instead of the local copy.
```

Comment: Letting multiple people modify the same System object at the same time is asking for all kinds of trouble as stated in your post. Why not lock down a module object so that only one client can modify it at one time?

Comment: Good point. I have done it at the API level, but that is not locking the actual object. Problem doing this is the client will have to be the one to decide when it is time to release that object. Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: No, that is what I am suggesting, but if you are worried about a client not releasing the object, say they disconnect from the interface or something without releasing the module, you could run some kind of clean up script which releases the module after so much time has elapsed or give some kind of Admin control to release modules for modification

Comment: Mmmh, that sounds tricky…. How about the Automatic setting of properties, any suggestion?